# How do I attach two files, it said to connect them but it's not working properly, and I keep getting errors

Tags: java

I am trying to call for DevideByZeroo but it keeps saying cannot find symbol.

I've already tried changing it to super, and i keep getting reds.

```
package CatchBlock;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
/**
 *
 * @author Moe
 */
public class catchblock {
     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        boolean invalid = true;
        Scanner Pad = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
        double r = 0;
        while(invalid)
        {
            try{
                System.out.print("Enter first Integer: ");
                i1 = Pad.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
                i2 = Pad.nextInt();
                if(i2 == 0)
                    DevideByZeroo("Cannot divide by Zero");
                r = (double) i1/i2;
                invalid = false;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                Pad.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
            }
            catch(DevideByZeroo e)
            {
                Pad.nextLine();
                System.out.println(e.GetMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i1 + " divided by " + i2 + " is " + r + ".");
    }

}
```

and

```
package CatchBlock;

/**
 *
 * @author Moe
 */
public class Divide extends catchblock {

    public String DevideByZeroo() {
        return  "Error: Dividing by Zero is impossible";
    }

    public String DevideByZeroo(String message){
        return message;
    }
}
```

It's supposed to ask for some integers and make sure we are not dividing by zero. now I'm running into issues being able to see the class in the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are going for custom exception, you'll need to extend Exception class. You should also append the word 'Exception' at the end of the name your custom exception classes. So your code for DevideByZeroo class should be like this:-

```
package CatchBlock;
public class DevideByZerooException extends Exception {

    DevideByZerooException() {
        super("Error: Dividing by Zero is impossible");
    }

    DevideByZerooException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And accordingly your code for catchblock class will also change like this:-

```
package CatchBlock;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
/**
 *
 * @author Moe
 */
public class catchblock {
     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // TODO code application logic here
        boolean invalid = true;
        Scanner Pad = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
        double r = 0;
        while(invalid)
        {
            try{
                System.out.print("Enter first Integer: ");
                i1 = Pad.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
                i2 = Pad.nextInt();
                if(i2 == 0)
                    throw new DevideByZerooException("Cannot divide by Zero");
                r = (double) i1/i2;
                invalid = false;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                Pad.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
            }
            catch(DevideByZerooException e)
            {
                Pad.nextLine();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i1 + " divided by " + i2 + " is " + r + ".");
    }
}
```

As a part of good practices you should keep package name in lowercase & start class names with capital letter & class should be preferably a noun.

Comment: Appending word exception in your custom exception class is also a part of good industry practices. Your code will anyways run irrespective of whatever name you keep.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a name for an exception class that does not exist.

- The spelling is wrong.  "Divide By Zero" not "Devide By Zeroo"
- Any standard exception will end with `Exception` or `Error`.
- In fact, the standard exception that gets thrown when you divide by zero is `ArithmeticException`; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html).

---

And if `DevideByZeroo` is supposed to be a custom exception:

- This is not how you throw and exception:

  ```
  DevideByZeroo("Cannot divide by Zero");
  ```

  It should be:

  ```
  throw new DevideByZeroo("Cannot divide by Zero");
  ```
- You need to declare the `DevideByZeroo` class.  If you declare it in the same package as your main class then you won't need to `import` it.  (You don't "attach" classes!)

It is generally a bad idea to declare a custom class when an existing standard class already exists.  But if you do define a custom class, you should follow the Java conventions:

- Exception names end with `Exception`.
- Spelling should be correct in the language that you are using.

<sup>Because it really grates to see bad spelling in class and method names.  It is like a child scraping their fingernails down a blackboard!  If your spelling is not good, use an online dictionary.</sup>

---

I note this:

```
public class Divide extends catchblock {
   ...
}
```

That is not declaring an exception class.

---

You have made so many errors here that I think that the *best* thing you could do is to read the **entire** Oracle Java tutorial lesson on exceptions:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

That explains how to declare a custom exception class.  Read it!